# How do I find which cells are selected on an Excel worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I need to be able to use C# and Excel interop to determine which cells are selected in a workbook/worksheet.  It would be nice if there were something like this defined in Excel:

```
Excel.Range Worksheet.GetSelectedCells();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Application.Selection` which will return a Range.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the ActiveCell property of the Excel Application  object. It would return you a Range object.