# Dealing with large selection ranges in Excel interop

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OutofMemory Exception Object Array Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823615/outofmemory-exception-object-array-size)

I am trying to capture a spreadsheet data in to a 2D array. I am using VSTO.

```
int rc = 1048576;
int cc = 1638;

string[,] arr = new string[rc, cc];
```

The last line throws Out of Memory exception. I would like to show message telling the user only 'X' elements can be captured.

Checked MSDN and there is a row count limit mentioned of 16,777,216 for the data-table.So a data table can hold data of size of a worksheet. Cant find limit either for 2D array.

My issue is not with WHY the exception. What I am looking for is if you are doing VSTO development, and had to capture a worksheet in a DataTable to perform In-Memory joins etc, you will need to do this:

```
string[,] arr = new string[rc, cc]; 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range selection 
arr = selection.Value as string[,];
```

and then copy the data from that array to data table. Now what will be the ideal limit for number of elements a user should select. So I can set that rowcount/columncount lmits and display message when selection exceeds this criteria. 
OR is there any other way to create a data table based on selected range in a worksheet, considering first row is always Column headers.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create your own class:

```
    public class MyClass {   
 public static string col1 {get;set;}   
 public static string col2 {get;set;}  
  public static string col3 {get;set;}   
 //etc for every column

}
```

read the first row into the properties of MyClass

then read every row of your worksheet into a list like this:

```
List<string> myList = new IList<string>();

myList.append(anInstanceofMyClass);
```

repeat for every row of data

Comment: I have to add only selected range's data. In that case both columns and row count vary depending on user's selection on spreadsheet. Class makes sense to me only when the number of columns are fix. Consider a scenario where user selects whole spreadsheet, one row and all columns. Do I create a class with 16,384 Column properties ?

Comment: great point! what is the issue with copying the selected data into a variable and writing the variable to a file?